# Using ContainerList with ImageDownloadService

Tags: java-me, lwuit, imagedownload, lwuit-list

I was referring to this [code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXhlghkgsHE) here. This suffices my need but I need to display the contents in 2 columns instead of 1. Hence, I thought of using a ContainerList with grid layout. The problem here is that the `boolean initListModel(List cmp)` is not getting called for the containerList.

I also tried to dynamically add the ContainerList but am having problems while using it with ImageDownloadService, the way it was used in case of List. It would be great if anyone could  provide me with any sample code to get along

Comment: @Shai Almog : could use some of your help.

Comment: There were many bugs in those classes in LWUIT. We haven't touched them in over 2 years and no longer support them. I suggest migrating to Codename One.

Comment: but I have to use some of the Nokia api's also. Hence, I am developing in Nokia IDE. Can the migration be done along with nokia api's in Nokia IDE?

Comment: Even Nokia has abandoned J2ME/Asha you seriously expect us to maintain a 3 year old version of LWUIT?